# Unable to reset my Singleton Services provided inRoot

Tags: angular, typescript, singleton, angular-services

I have made a singleton service that updates the data from view to view. So I am using them as DTOs within the view. This main singleton service references other singleton services. Within the main service I have a reset() function that is supposed to return the properties on the main service to their original values and reference the peripheral singleton service reset() methods.
Unfortunately instead of doing the later part it is overwriting the main singleton service's references to the peripheral singleton services with a new property (named the same thing as the reference put in the constructor of the main service) but must somehow still be accessing that peripheral service's method so it knows what to set this new property to.

Why isn't it recognizing the org in the org constructor???
[image]

Why doesn't this reset method work?  Is there a better way/ best practice for doing this?  Thank you.

Below I have supplied the main singleton along with the singletons that are referenced within.

Please let me know if I need to clarify.

Main Singleton

```
import { OrgAdmin } from './../org-admin.model';
import { Permission } from './../permission.model';
import { UserRequest } from "../user-request.model";
import { Customer } from "../customer.model";
import { SecurityProfileDto } from "../security-profile-dto";
import { Org } from "../org.model";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class OrgViewModel {
  // current forms
  orgInfo: Org = this.org;
  currentOrgAdmin: UserRequest = this.user;
  currentSecProfile: SecurityProfileDto = this.secProf;

  // current mapping grid
  orgAdmins: UserRequest[] = [];
  customers: Customer[] = [];
  secProfiles: SecurityProfileDto[] = [];
  railroadfilters: string[] = [];


  orgAdminsValidity: string = 'invalid'; // invalid, incomplete, valid
  customersValidity: string = 'invalid'; // invalid, incomplete, valid
  secProfilesValidity: string = 'invalid'; // invalid, incomplete, valid
  filtersValidity: string = 'invalid'; // invalid, incomplete, valid

  // meta orgViewModel
  isFinalized: boolean = false;
  isNew: boolean = false;

  valid: boolean = false; // invalid, incomplete, valid
  done: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private org: Org,
    private user: UserRequest,
    private orgAdmin: OrgAdmin,
    private secProf: SecurityProfileDto,
  ) { }

  reset() {
    this.org.reset();
    this.orgAdmin.reset();
    this.secProf.reset();
    this.orgAdmins = [];
    this.orgAdminsValidity = 'invalid'; // invalid, incomplete, valid
    this.customers = [];
    this.customersValidity = 'invalid'; // invalid, incomplete, valid
    this.secProfiles = [];
    this.secProfilesValidity = 'invalid'; // invalid, incomplete, valid
    this.railroadfilters = [];
    this.filtersValidity = 'invalid'; // invalid, incomplete, valid

    this.isFinalized = false;
    this.isNew = false;
    this.valid = false;
    this.done = false;
    console.log('orgVM Model : CLEARED ');
  }

  get complete() {
    return this.valid && this.done;
  }
}
```

Organization singleton

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class Org {
  id: string = "";
  orgName: string = "";
  active: boolean = false;
  isMakerChecker: boolean = false;
  addressLine1: string = "";
  addressLine2: string = "";
  state: string = "";
  city: string = "";
  postalCode: string = "";
  country: string = "";
  telephone: string = "";
  ext: string = "";
  domain: string = "";
  adminIds: string[];
  userIds: string[];
  securityProfileIds: string[];

  isActive: boolean = false;
  new: boolean = true;
  validity: boolean = false;
  complete: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  reset() {
    this.id = "";
    this.orgName = "";
    this.active = false;
    this.isMakerChecker = false;
    this.addressLine1 = "";
    this.addressLine2 = "";
    this.state = "";
    this.city = "";
    this.postalCode = "";
    this.country = "";
    this.telephone = "";
    this.ext = "";
    this.domain = "";
    this.adminIds = [];
    this.userIds = [];
    this.securityProfileIds = [];

    this.isActive = false;
    this.new = true;
    this.validity = false;
    this.complete = false;
  }
}
```

User request singleton

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { UserReqValidStateService } from "../services/UserManagement/UserReqValidState.service";

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserRequest {
  id: string = "";
  userType: number = 0;
  firstName: string = "";
  lastName: string = "";
  cellPhone: string = "";
  officePhone: string = "";
  ext: string = "";
  fax: string = "";
  country: string = "";
  state: string = "";
  city: string = "";
  requesterId: string = "";
  orgId: string = "";
  supervisorId: string = "";
  securityProfileIds: string[] = [];
  emailAddress: string = "";

  isActive: boolean = false;
  userState: number = 0; // this is mainly for backend. 0 = submitted, 1 = approved, 2 = completed... in the future 3 = submittedButFailed
  new: boolean = true;
  validity: boolean = false;
  complete: boolean = false;

  constructor(private validstate: UserReqValidStateService) { }

  reset() {
    this.id = "";
    this.userType = 0;
    this.firstName = "";
    this.lastName = "";
    this.cellPhone = "";
    this.officePhone = "";
    this.ext = "";
    this.fax = "";
    this.country = "";
    this.state = "";
    this.city = "";
    this.requesterId = "";
    this.orgId = "";
    this.supervisorId = "";
    this.securityProfileIds = [];
    this.emailAddress = "";

    this.isActive = false;
    this.userState = 0; // this is mainly for the backend Control layer. 0 = submitted, 1 = approved, 2 = completed... in the future 3 = submittedButFailed
    this.new = true;
    this.validity = false;
    this.complete = false;


    this.validstate.stateCompUserInfoValid.subscribe(userInfoValid => this.validity = userInfoValid);


    console.log('USER REQUEST SINGLETON RESET');
  }
}
```

Org admin singleton

```
import { UserRequest } from "./user-request.model";

// THIS IS THE SAME AS USER REQUEST but we want to segrate the persistance in memory here

export class OrgAdmin extends UserRequest {

}
```

Security Profiles singleton

```
import { Permission } from "./permission.model";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SecurityProfileDto {
  id: string = "";
  name: string = "";
  customerCodes: string[] = [];
  permissionCodes: string[] = [];
  orgId: string = "";

  new: boolean = true;
  validity: string = 'invalid';

  constructor() {

  }

  reset() {
    this.id = "";
    this.name = "";
    this.customerCodes = [];
    this.permissionCodes = [];
    this.orgId = "";
    this.new = true;
    this.validity = 'invalid';
    console.log('SEC PROFILE RESET');
  }

}
```

Org Management component (I am aware I need to refactor... deadlines)

```
import { Org } from './../../../shared/models/org.model';
import { SecurityProfileDto } from './../../../shared/models/security-profile-dto';
import { SecProfService } from './../../../shared/services/webapi/sec-prof.service';
import { OrgViewModel } from './../../../shared/models/org/org-view.model';
import { Component, OnInit, DoCheck, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { slideToRight } from '../../../router.animations';
import { AgGridAbstractService } from '../../../shared/components/ag-grid-abstract/ag-grid-abstract';
import { GridAdminsRenderer } from '../../../shared/components/grid-admins/grid-admins.component';
import { GridStatusRenderer } from '../../../shared/components/grid-status/grid-status.component';
import { ViewMoreRenderer } from '../../../shared/components/grid-view-more-org/view-more.component';
import { BreadcrumbService } from '../../../shared/services/Nav/Breadcrumb.service';
import { OrgViewStateService } from '../../../shared/services/OrgManagement/OrgState.service';
import { OrgsService } from '../../../shared/services/webapi/orgs.service';
import { GlobalEvent$Service } from '../../../shared/services/global-event$.service';
import { UserRequestService } from '../../../shared/services/webapi/user-request.service';
import { UserRequest } from '../../../shared/models/user-request.model';
import { GridSecprofilesUserRenderer } from '../../../shared/components/grid/grid-secprofiles-user/grid-secprofiles-user.component';
import { GridSecprofilesOrgRenderer } from '../../../shared/components/grid/grid-secprofiles-org/grid-secprofiles-org.component';
import { OrgAdmin } from '../../../shared/models/org-admin.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'org-management-blade',
  templateUrl: './org-management-blade.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./org-management-blade.component.css'],
  animations: [slideToRight()]
})
export class OrgManagementBladeComponent extends AgGridAbstractService implements OnInit, DoCheck, OnDestroy {
  level2: string;

  public isHoveredEditOrg = false;

  public usingService = 'orgServiceTable';

  // ag-Grid
  public rowData: any;
  public test: any;

  public headerHeight;
  public context;
  public frameworkComponents;
  public gridApi;
  public gridColumnApi;
  public cellRendererObject;

  public seeViewOrg = false;

  public response: any;
  refresh: boolean;
  admin: UserRequest;

  cellClicked: any;

  constructor(
    private org: Org,
    private viewstate: OrgViewStateService,
    private crumbstate: BreadcrumbService,

    // ag-Grid
    private orgservice: OrgsService<any>,
    private userservice: UserRequestService<UserRequest>,
    private secprofservice: SecProfService<SecurityProfileDto>,
    private orgVM: OrgViewModel,
    public globalEvent$: GlobalEvent$Service,
  ) {
    // ag-Grid
    super();
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: 'Active',
        field: 'isActive',
        cellRenderer: "gridStatusRenderer",
        colId: "viewmore",
        suppressResize: true,
        suppressFilter: true,
        width: 55
      },
      { headerName: 'Organization', field: 'orgName', width: 200 },
      {
        headerName: 'Admins',
        field: 'adminIds',
        cellRenderer: "gridAdminsRenderer",
        colId: "admins",
        width: 100
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Security <br> Profiles',
        field: 'securityProfileIds',
        cellRenderer: "gridSecprofilesOrgRenderer",
        colId: "secprofiles",
        width: 100
      },
      { headerName: 'Domain', field: 'domain', cellStyle: { 'text-align': 'right' }, width: 100 },
      {
        headerName: 'View More',
        field: 'viewMore',
        cellRenderer: "viewMoreRenderer",
        colId: "params",
        suppressFilter: true,
        suppressResize: true,
        sortingOrder: [null],
        width: 75
      },
    ];
    this.context = { componentParent: this };
    this.frameworkComponents = {
      gridStatusRenderer: GridStatusRenderer,
      gridAdminsRenderer: GridAdminsRenderer,
      gridSecprofilesOrgRenderer: GridSecprofilesOrgRenderer,
      viewMoreRenderer: ViewMoreRenderer,
    };
    this.headerHeight = 45;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // ag-Grid THIS IS THE ONE LINER THAT BRINGS IN THE DATA
    this.rowData = this.orgservice.getListo();
    this.orgservice.getListo();

    this.viewstate.currentLevel2.subscribe(level2 => this.level2 = level2);
    this.crumbstate.changeLevel1(' > Organization Management');

    this.globalEvent$.currentGlobalEvent.subscribe(res => {
      this.refresh = res;
      console.log('this.refresh: ', this.refresh);
    });
  }

  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    if (this.agGrid !== undefined && this.refresh === true) {
      console.log("cells refreshed");
      console.log('this.refresh: ', this.refresh);
      this.refreshCells();
      this.refresh = false;
    }
  }

  refreshCells() {
    this.rowData = this.orgservice.getListo();
    this.agGrid.api.setRowData(this.rowData);
    // this.viewstate.changeLevel1(null);
    // this.viewstate.changeLevel1("orgBlade");
  }

  clearOrgVM() {
    // this.orgVM.reset();

    // this.org.id = "";
    // this.org.orgName = "";
    // this.org.active = false;
    // this.org.isMakerChecker = false;
    // this.org.addressLine1 = "";
    // this.org.addressLine2 = "";
    // this.org.state = "";
    // this.org.city = "";
    // this.org.postalCode = "";
    // this.org.country = "";
    // this.org.telephone = "";
    // this.org.ext = "";
    // this.org.domain = "";
    // this.org.adminIds = [];
    // this.org.userIds = [];
    // this.org.securityProfileIds = [];

    this.orgVM = null;

    console.log('this.orgVM: CLEARED', this.orgVM);
  }

  // this uses ag-Grid api to transfer data from the child cell renderer to this parent instance
  cellRendererMethodFromParent(cell) {
    this.cellRendererObject = cell;
    console.log('cellRendererObject: ', this.cellRendererObject);
  }

  mapClickToModel() {
    // this.orgVM = new OrgViewModel;
    console.log('this.getSelectedRows(): ', this.getSelectedRows());

    // grab the data available from the grid without making a call
    this.orgVM.orgInfo = this.getSelectedRows()[0];
    // if (this.getSelectedRows()[0]) {
    //   this.orgVM.orgInfo = this.getSelectedRows()[0];
    // } else {
      //   this.orgVM.reset();
      // }

    // add frontend meta data
    this.orgVM.orgInfo.new = false;
    this.orgVM.orgInfo.validity = true;
    // reset arrays
    const orgadmins = [];
    const secprofs = [];
    // these ids would have to be used to get and spread these profiles into the orgVM array
    this.getSelectedRows()[0].adminIds.map(x => {
      this.userservice.getObjecto(x).subscribe(y => { orgadmins.push(y); console.log('y', y); });
    });
    this.orgVM.orgAdmins = orgadmins;
    this.getSelectedRows()[0].securityProfileIds.map(x => {
      this.secprofservice.getObjecto(x).subscribe(y => { y.new = false; secprofs.push(y); console.log('y', y); });
    });
    this.orgVM.secProfiles = secprofs;

    // this.orgVM.orgAdmins = this.getSelectedRows()[0].adminIds;
    // this.orgVM.secProfiles = this.getSelectedRows()[0].securityProfileIds;

    console.log('this.orgVM.orgInfo: ', this.orgVM.orgInfo);
    console.log('this.orgVM.orgAdmins: ', this.orgVM.orgAdmins);
    console.log('this.orgVM.customers: ', this.orgVM.customers);
    console.log('this.orgVM.secProfiles: ', this.orgVM.secProfiles);
    console.log('this.orgVM click finished: ', this.orgVM);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.crumbstate.changeLevel1(null);
  }

  newLevel2(state) {
    this.viewstate.changeLevel2(state);
  }

  isSelectedNewLevel2() {
    if (this.orgVM.orgInfo.id) {
      this.viewstate.changeLevel2('orgEdit');
    }
  }


  newLevel3(state) {
    this.viewstate.changeLevel3(state);
  }
}
```

First window shows three attempts at clearing the data
Second window shows where the event occurs
Third window, back in the component, shows where data IS succesfully being put onto the singleton (but then I can't clear it hence the problem)
[image]

Comment: Is the issue just that the values don't get reset? Do your `console.log`s get printed?

Comment: Yes, I am able to load other values into them normally but when it comes to using that reset function it does not work.  The console logs are jiving with what I see in the view (that the data is not getting reset), so I don't think it is a matter of me cutting off the connection to the singleton somewhere.

Comment: Okay, so you're not seeing the logs printed to the console then? Can you please show the code where you're called `reset` on the main singleton?

Comment: Added.  I am seeing the information change in the console, ill add a picture of that too

Comment: The line where you call `this.orgVM.reset()` is commented out?

Comment: Probably wasn't too clear... "First window shows three attempts at clearing the data"

Comment: I posted a final picture about what is going on.  For some reason it is making a new property called org on OrgViewModel class instead of using the org in the constructor and accessing its reset(). Do you know why its doing this? If you do can you put it in an answer so I can close it out and give you thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reset() AND THEN set the reference back to the main object.

This method leaves extra properties within your object which I tried to delete so as not to confuse but this caused problem which I am sure resulted because it thought I was trying to delete the properties coming from the constructor.

...I'm sure there's a better pattern for keeping a singleton around. Please let me know if you have the magiks.

[image]
[image]